# Using Arrays.sort() for non-alphabetical characters such as {'+' '1' 'D'}

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, char

My example string is "D+1"

I transfer it into a array of characters

I want to sort them so that it comes out ASCII style, so it'd be {'+', '1', 'D'}

Then I can manually move the operator, '+' in this case, to the middle how I want it so when I turn it back into a String it becomes "1+D"

Arrays.sort() doesn't work in this case, is there a ubiquitous fix?

This would save me having to make a whole bunch of entries into a hash map

```
if (comp.length()>2)
    {
        char[] compChars = comp.toCharArray();

        boolean exit = false;
        if (compChars[1] == '-')
            exit = true;

        // if there is no subtraction
        if (!exit) {

            // TODO: fix
            Arrays.sort(compChars);
            char temp = compChars[0];
            compChars[0] = compChars[1];
            compChars[1] = temp;

            comp = String.valueOf(comp);

        }

    }
```

Comment: _hint:_ An [overloaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) method of `Arrays.sort` takes a comparator.

Comment: What is the the form of the input strings (`comp`)? you give an example, but what is the general rule?

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): What is the original problem? Will the output of `"AB - 21"` be `"21 - AB"` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your example worked perfectly fine for "D+1". The only error in it is that in the last line you need
`comp = String.valueOf(compChars);`